# MySql запрос на добавление записи

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `test` 
SET
id=NULL,
sub_id=//Выполнить SELECT запрос к таблице test получить максимальное значение sub_id и увеличить на 1
name='Pupka'
```

Поле `id` имеет начальный `auto_increment 1000`, а `sub_id` `unsigned` по дефолту `1`. Нужно увеличивать значение `sub_id` на 1 при добавлении новой записи в таблицу.

Подскажите как выполнить такой запрос, или возможно есть другое более простое решени?

UPD:

Запрос выполнить я знаю как, но проблема конкретно в том что запрос отдает ошибку `You can't specify target table 'test' for update in FROM clause` по всей видимости из-за того что INSERT и SELECT обращаются к одной таблице.

UPD2:

Пока влезвло в голову создать таблицу `some_values` с полем `tb_test_sub_id` сделать туда соответствующую запись, и делать следующий запрос

```
UPDATE `some_values` SET `tb_test_sub_id`=`tb_test_sub_id`+1;

INSERT INTO `test` 
SET
id=NULL,
sub_id=(SELECT `tb_test_sub_id` FROM `some_values`)+1,
name='Pupka'
```

Результат тот что нужен

```
+------------------+
+ 1244 | 1 | Pupka +
+ 1245 | 2 | Pupka +
+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Поле sub_id сделать автоинкрементным

Comment: 1. втоинкремент может быть только 1


2. Если даже, то в таком случает поля `id` и `sub_id` будут иметь одинаковые значение, чего мне абсолютно ненужно!

Comment: Так какая задача - id должен начинаться с тысячи, а sub_id с единицы?

Comment: Именно так!

Comment: Тогда в sub_id нет никакого смысла - ее значение можно получить из id. В MS SQL для этого можно использовать определение колонки sub_id AS id-999, в MySQL - ну наверно триггер можно предложить